# Properties passed to a WPF resource control evaluate in data context of the resource host

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got a user control that uses data triggers to determine what type of tab content is displayed for each tab item in a collection.

The tab contents come from user controls, and these have dependency properties of their own to control their content.

The values passed into these dependency properties should be bound to the properties of the corresponding tab item from the collection.

Here's some trimmed down and simplified code of my structure:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.TabArea"
    ...
>
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">
        <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}">
            <TabControl.Resources>
                <local:SomeDetail x:Key="SomeDetailControl" x:Shared="False" Prop="{Binding PropValue}" PropTwo="{Binding PropTwoValue}" />
            </TabControl.Resources>
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                ...
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>

            <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyBinding}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource SomeDetailControl}" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        ...
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I've placed the detail user control in the resources for the tab control, marked it as not shared, and added some bindings.

It was my understanding that these bindings were evaluated when the controls were used, in that context. However, I get a binding error that `PropValue` etc. can't be found on the user control.

Initially I wondered if the *data context for the Grid* was throwing this off, but removing it just moves the error out to the containing component.

I also tried *moving the resources around to the grid* and the style itself to no avail.

How do I ensure that the bindings for the resource attached properties come from the tab item object?

Answer (score 0):

> I've got a user control that uses data triggers to determine what type of tab content is displayed for each tab item in a collection.

You should use a `ContentTemplateSelector` to selected the appropriate `DataTemplate`: https://jacobaloysious.wordpress.com/2013/08/19/mvvm-using-contenttemplateselector-in-tab-control-view/

Or you could try to use a `ContentTemplate`:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">
    <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}">
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate.Resources>
                    <local:SomeDetail x:Key="SomeDetailControl" x:Shared="False"  Prop="{Binding PropValue}" PropTwo="{Binding PropTwoValue}" />
                </DataTemplate.Resources>
                <ContentControl>
                    <ContentControl.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                            <Setter Property="Content">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <TextBlock>default template...</TextBlock>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyBinding}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource SomeDetailControl}" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </ContentControl.Style>
                </ContentControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: The `ContentTemplate` approach seems nicer, but I'm running into an issue I thought I'd solved with moving things as unshared resources: The controls now seem to be "shared" between tabs. For example, a textbox in one tab when modified will also be modified in another tab with the same control.

Comment: That's why you should define two DataTemplates and use a ContentTemplateSelector to selected the appropriate one based on the value of your MyBinding property.

Comment: Or bind the TextBox to a source property.

Comment: See my slighly edited XAML. This will create a new instance of the UC for each time. Note that it will be re-created each time that you switch to the tab though. That's how a TabControl works and that's why you need to bind all properties that you intend to keep between tab switches to source properties of your data object.